# How Can I expand the list and choose dynamic value.

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find out the solution how to get the target of **Add New** from **Prod2** from the code below.

To get this target at first I have to click on **ptv-icon ptv-collapse-icon**. This is possible using XPATH but each time when I run the script xpath is changing.

Does it possible to use any method to localize **Add New** directly.

Another problem is that: **Add New** element is only visible after I will click on **ptv-icon ptv-collapse-icon**.

```
<li class="ptv-listitem" data-id="1">
<div class="ptv-item">
<span class="ptv-icon ptv-expand-icon"></span>
<span class="ptv-text">
<span class="tree-text">Prod1</span>
<span class="tree-counts"></span>
</span>
</div>
</li>
<li class="ptv-listitem" data-id="2">
<div class="ptv-item">
<span class="ptv-icon ptv-collapse-icon"></span>
<span class="ptv-text ptv-selected">
<span class="tree-text">Prod2</span>
<span class="tree-counts"></span>
</span>
</div>
<ul class="ptv-list ptx-expanded">
<li class="ptv-listitem" data-id="-1">
<div class="ptv-item">
<span class="ptv-text">
<span class="tree-text">**Add New**</span>
<span class="tree-counts"></span>
</span>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</li
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming you're using Java) You should try using `xpath` with text which would never be change as below :-

```
//to click on prod2
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[contains(.,'Prod2')]//span[@class = 'ptv-icon ptv-expand-icon']").click();

//to click on add new
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//li[contains(.,'Add New')]"))).click();
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code is the best suitable for my problem. Only I've had to replace some parts **contains** to **starts-with**

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element by the 2 classes of ul and one class of the span:

```
WebDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.ptv-list.ptx-expanded span.tree-text")).click()
```

This means select a `span` element having `tree-text` class, which is inside an `ul` elemenent having both `ptv-list` and `ptx-expanded` classes.